# yocto poky-tiny does not create rcS symbolic links

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build poky-tiny based system but faced with problem - it does not create symbolic links to the init scripts which are placed in /etc/init.d/

poky-tiny is using busybox-inittab and accordingto the busybox recipe:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
It has INITSCRIPT_NAME and INITSCRIPT_PARAMS variables defined which are used in  https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/update-rc.d.bbclass
I expect that it should create for example link /etc/rcS.d/S10syslog -> /etc/ini.d/syslog, the init script /etc/ini.d/syslog is installed but I dont see any symbolic links and folder /etc/rcS at all.

Of cause I can create this manual but I prefer to use standard yocto way of adding init scripts to system bootup.

How to add syslog to system startup while normal poky-tiny build ?

Answer (score 0):

poky-tiny doesn't set / removes "sysvinit" from DISTRO_FEATURES. This is required for having symlinks in rootfs / after package installation.